# Overlap element on hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overlap

I want a bootstrap panels header to expand on hover, but it must not push down the next panel as shown in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2jwg0a35/2/.

What I want is that when you hover over the panel heading, it'll overlap the panel-body instead of pushing down the next.

My HTML is just twitter bootstrap stuff and looks like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <img src="profile-pic.jpg" alt="Profile pic" />
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body"> <b>John Do</b>

        <br/>J.do@example.com
        <br/>Somestreet
        <br/> <b>City</b>

        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS looks like:

```
.panel-heading {
    height:100px;
}
.panel-heading:hover {
    height:150px; /*This actually must be 100% as there will be an image in it.*/
    position:relative;
}
```

Anybody knows what I can do to achieve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: it works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/2jwg0a35/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for ?

http://jsfiddle.net/2jwg0a35/5/

Put your panel-heading to `absolute`, your `panel-default` to `relative` and add `padding-top` to your `panel-body`. The `padding-top` must be the same height of the panel-heading `height`.

```
.panel-heading {
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.panel-heading:hover {
    height:150px;
}
.panel-default{
    position: relative; /* contain the absolute heading */
}
.panel-body{
    padding-top: 100px; /* Must be === to .panel-heading height */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Give at the panel-heading a negative `margin-bottom`: http://jsfiddle.net/2jwg0a35/4/

Comment: `+1` for nice answer. I marked `Berthy's` answer as answer because in your Fiddle the `panel-header` must always be the same height when hovered on. So the image in the `panel-header` cannot have a variable `height` and with `Berthy's` answer it doesn't matter what the height of the image is as long as the panel-body has a `padding-top` which has to be the same as the `panel-header` when not hovered on. Thanks though for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
 .panel{
 border:1px solid transparent;
 }
 .panel-heading {
 height:100px;
 }
 .panel-heading:hover {
 height:150px; /*This actually must be 100% as there will be an image in it.*/
 position: absolute;
 width:100%;
 }
 .panel-heading:hover + .panel-body{
 margin-top:100px;
 }
```